# Is there a Newton-like equation for gravity that gives equivalent results to that of general relatively?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity

It seems like you might be able to create a time dependent version of Newton's law of gravity. Perhaps it would also require terms for non-radial dimensions along with time.

Maxwell's equations fit into Special Relativity even though the equations came before the theory. Perhaps if time or space dilations were known to some degree before General Relatively then there would be a more complex time dependent form of Newton's equation for gravity.

Does one exist, has anyone tried to create one, or is there some reason why this would be impossible?

Comment: Define these terms: time dependent version of Newton's gravity, non-radial dimension, time and space dilation, and equations came from theory?!     Having that said there are some modified Newtonian gravity to explain dark matter but they are not very successful.

Comment: Do you know [Einstein-Infeld-Hoffmann equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Infeld%E2%80%93Hoffmann_equations)?

Comment: @Qmechanic, no I dont. What were they trying to do when they created those equations? Do you think they explain the precession of mercury?

Comment: @KianMaleki, I didnt state "equations came from theory" (is that a typo?) and not sure I see why these other ones need to be defined.

Comment: The E-I-H equations can be used to numerically calculate the motion of planets in the solar system, taking GR corrections into account, and all the gravitational effects of planets on other planets. But, as far as I know, they are not the way to get the simple analytic expression for the precession of Mercury’s orbit. That comes from looking at geodesics for the Schwarzschild metric. This metric describes the exterior gravitational field of stars, not just black holes.

Comment: The purpose of the E-I-H equations is to make General Relativity look like Newtonian gravity plus various small corrections, when the gravitational fields are weak and the velocities of masses are small compared to the speed of light. They involve a kind of series expansion, in a small parameter, of the $n$-body problem within GR.

Answer (score 5):

Physicists have tried simple extensions to Newtonian gravity to make it compatible with Special Relativity. For example, [Nordström’s 1912 theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordstr%C3%B6m%27s_theory_of_gravitation) replaced the [Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Newtonian_gravity) relating the Newtonian gravitational potential $\varphi$ to the mass density $\rho$,

$$\nabla^2\varphi=4\pi G\rho,$$

with the obvious special-relativistic generalization,

$$\nabla^2\varphi-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial t^2}=4\pi G\rho.$$

This is a wave-like equation. It predicted gravitational waves, pre-Einstein!

Unfortunately, this theory does not agree with observation, nor do other simple extensions of Newtonian gravity.

Going in the other direction,  one can start with General Relativity, consider the problem of $N$ gravitating masses in the case where their gravitational fields are weak and their velocities slow (such as for planets in a solar system), and make their equations of motion look like Newtonian gravity plus various small corrections. The result is known as the [Einstein-Infeld-Hoffmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Infeld%E2%80%93Hoffmann_equations).

They are a kind of series expansion of General Relativity in powers of $1/c$, where the lowest order terms with no $1/c$ are the Newtonian theory. The expansion has been carried to several orders higher than the $1/c^2$ corrections shown in Wikipedia, so it can be extremely accurate.

These equations are integrated to make [planetary ephemerides](https://www.iers.org/SharedDocs/Publikationen/EN/IERS/Publications/tn/TechnNote36/tn36_028.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1), such as for interplanetary spacecraft navigation. It is much easier to deal with these equations than the field and geodesic equations of General Relativity.

Physicists could never have guessed the Einstein-Infeld-Hoffmann equations. Since they are a series expansion, they are not simple and elegant. They can only be derived by starting from General Relativity, which, in its own way, is just as simple and elegant as Newton’s theory.